# How to access the console output of invoker integration test in post-build script?

Tags: java, maven, maven-invoker-plugin

I have a [post-build script](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/examples/post-build-script.html) written in Groovy in my [maven-invoker-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/index.html) setup. How can I access the console output of an integration test in this script? I want to check that certain text has been printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire log is stored into the `build.log` file, which is placed in the [`logDirectory`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#logDirectory).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the property you are looking for:

https://github.com/apache/maven-invoker-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/invoker/AbstractInvokerMojo.java#L147

**Property:** `invoker.streamLogs`
**Default value:** `false`
**Description:** Flag used to determine whether the build logs
should be output to the normal mojo log.

See this method for how logging is handled:

https://github.com/apache/maven-invoker-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/invoker/AbstractInvokerMojo.java#L2226

Comment: What is the name of the variable to use inside the post-build script to read the content of the log?